# Benefit of running Storm under supervision, example/sample code

Tags: apache-storm, topology

I have installed the storm correctly. But, I am struggling how to run an example on storm. Can anyone please give me the link or suggestion by which I can execute the example?
Also, what are the benefit of running storm under supervision?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the storm on your local machine then you have an example storm project bundled along it which you can find in the examples/storm-starter of your storm repository.

To run this example you can follow the series of steps mentioned in README.markdown file in the root folder of storm-starter folder. The steps can also be found at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/v0.10.0/examples/storm-starter

Regarding running storm and under supervision, the benefit is that since Storm and zookeeper have a fail fast policy, the servers will shutdown if there is an error. Using a supervisor process can bring up the servers in case of they exit the process because of errors.